# Android Studio: MotionEvent - touch tracking

Tags: android

I'm new to Java but handling it quite well because of my years of programming with python (basic concepts carry from language to language).

I have a practice project set up and the only propose of this project is for me to learn how to do things the java/android studio way, logic wise.

So logically, the last python based api I used, there was a way to issue your own ID to touches and keep track of those touches; therefore you knew if a touch still existed or not.

That's where I am right now.  I know how to get the touch ID and then get the Index that holds the touch data.  Basically I'm using a For Loop on the motion event to process all touches to the screen.

Here's the thing....

Lets say I have 10 touches to process and what I do in a loop is basically collect the info of the touches and store them in a hashtable, so I can then later process all the touches in the hashtable.

So as I pull a touch data from the hashtable to process, I want to first check to see if the touch still exits.  I'm guessing once a touch enters the "UP" state, it goes out of scope after that because a touch is over after release.

Sure I can just check the "Action" to see if it's equal to "UP" but if the touch doesn't exits anymore, that would raise and exception...right?

What I thought about doing was, calling "getPointerCount" again, looping through and getting the IDs again and see if the ID of a touch in my hashtable still exits in the MotionEvent and if the ID exists and the "Action" is still equal to "DOWN", then process the touch.  Otherwise, if the ID does not exists or the "ACTION" is equal to "UP", do a release button event if needed or just delete the touch from my hashtable because it doesn't exits anymore.

I can't help but get the feeling of redundancy though when considering that approach.

Is there a way or method I don't know about that allows you to check if a touch still exits before you process actions relating to it?

I was thinking just now....  Well, kind of guessing that, if you have five touches that hit the screen and one of the touches triggers the opening of a menu and that button had higher priority over the other four touches, you could simply ignore the other for touches for that frame and open the menu and in the next frame of the app, if the other four touches are still down, you can deal with them then accoring to their priority.....  But then again, the touch could still exists in the next frame but the "Action" may be "UP" or "MOVE" instead of down, thus allowing one to write code for a release or move event.  With this thought, storing touch data in a hashtable is really not needed then, granted a touch this is on action "UP" will go out of scope in the very next frame (I'm guessing).

......hum......

Maybe I'm just over thinking it.

Forgive any "typos", eyes are that super any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I wrote was correct but I wasn't getting the results because I was using MotionEvent.getAction().

For anyone new to Android Studio and its APIs, do not use MotionEvent.getAction().  Instead, use MotionEvent.getActionMasked()...otherwise, multi-touch will not work correctly.

For me, only the 1st touch was registering when I was doing a double button press test.  I thought my code was flawd but all was working correctly when I used MotionEvent.getActionMasked().

Turns out, MotionEvent.getAction() just doesn't return an Action...other data is attached to it, which throws off your code.

MotionEvent.getActionMasked() returns the Action only.